# How to differentiate between done and closed-for-other-reaons issues in GitLab?

Tags: project-management, issue-tracking, gitlab

In GitLab, an issue is usually closed once a Merge Request is approved and merged into master.

However, what should happen with issues that are closed because of other reasons? 
There could be various reasons for this:

- It turns out the issue is not needed.
- The issue turns out to be not feasible, would break too much stuff etc.
- ...

Should these issues be closed also? How can you then differentiate later between these and other closed issues, that have actually been done?

I would also be interested to know what should happen to merge requests related to such discarded issues.
I get the generally accepted approach is to close them, it is then easily possible to see that they were not in fact merged (closed VS merged is different in MRs).
However, in time, this puts a lot of closed merge requests into your system, even if they have no chance of ever being re-considered again. Also, what to do with the associated branches?

I would be interested in hearing recommendations or being pointed to in-depth discussions about the topic.